# What is the best way to deal with Vanity URL helpers in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web application I am working on with Rails 3 and I have just implemented some basic Vanity URL paths to existing resources in the application. What I am looking to do is to *not* have to explictly build the urls on the user's profile page for the resources that are available, e.g. I would like to be able to build a URL with link_to in the view in the format of:

```
typealoud.com/:user_id/:thread_id/:comment_id
```

And not what the standard nested resource helpers give me, something like:

```
typealoud.com/threads/:thread_id/comments/:comment_id
```

Should I do this myself as a URL helper, or is there an existing gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, I would put this at the top of my routes:

```
match ':user_id/:thread_id/:id', :to => "comments#show"
```

I've changed `comment_id` in this example to `id` because it's "The Rails Way" that the last id parameter is simply called `id`. It also results in shorter code.

If you wish to have a routing helper for it use the `:as` option:

```
match ':user_id/:thread_id/:id', :to => "comments#show", :as => "comment"
```

Then you can use `comment_path`/`comment_url`to access the route, but you must pass in three arguments to it, each of them being an object or an id of an object.

Comment: I dig it. Thanks for everything Ryan.